# Silverlight 2 UI pattern

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0, mvp, ria

I have to build small (for now) admin app in Silverlight2, and would like to use some pattern for binding UI with my BL/DAL.
I found view-model-viewmodel and mvp/mvc patterns, where first one (V/M/VM) is specially suited for WPF apps, because it uses rich capabilities of WPF data-binding options. What do you suggest? Can you write simple example of V/M/VM for SL2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nikhil Kothari has a great set of examples (with code) on M-V-VM in Silverlight as well as a framework built with some very nice extra features. You should definitely check them out.
[M-V-VM in Silverlight](http://nikhilk.net/Silverlight-ViewModel-Pattern.aspx)

Comment: Good link. Possibly one of the clearest explanations I've found on MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

The Patterns & Practices group at Microsoft has put together some guidance around doing [WPF and Silverlight](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF) applications.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [CSLA.NET for Silverlight](http://www.lhotka.net/cslalight/). I've heard good things about it but haven't gotten around to try it yet myself.

> CSLA .NET for Silverlight is a subset
>   of CSLA .NET targeted at the
>   Silverlight platform. CSLA .NET for
>   Silverlight offers nearly all the
>   benefits of CSLA .NET on Silverlight,
>   including data binding, validation,
>   business rules, authorization, n-level
>   undo and persistence.
>
> The result is that CSLA .NET for
>   Silverlight enables the creation of a
>   rich object-oriented business layer
>   running on the Silverlight client,
>   that can transparently communicate
>   with CSLA .NET objects running on the
>   web and application servers.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight has also very powerful data-binding, so there is no problem with that.

The missing piece in Silverlight that affects more to the Model-View-ViewModel pattern is that it doesn’t implements commands like WPF. [Here](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/joshs/archive/2008/11/17/putting-silverlight-commands-to-use.aspx) is an article by Josh Smith that reproduces the command pattern of WPF in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn Wildermuth of Wildermuth.com wrote an article about the MV-VM Pattern, check it out, here is the link of the article ["Model-View-ViewModel In Silverlight 2 Apps"](http://tinyurl.com/cpwbxc)

Answer (score 0):

Norwegian developer Gjøran had a very nice presentation/demo at MSDN Live about writing business apps in WPF. Really it was about using Presentation Model with Silverlight/WPF. Have a look at [the source code from this article on his blog](http://blog.goeran.no/PermaLink,guid,5e9eb4c4-163d-47aa-bbba-753700e848da.aspx) (sorry, the slides are in Norwegian only). [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) + silverlight 2 rocks!!!